# Giving notification when out of radius range google map android

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any possible to throw notification if i was outside of radius when it has been settled ?

My schema is like this :
i am a student and my phone has been installed tracker.
if i walk into outside range of school. my application will give notification to my mother that i have been skip the class using SMS / email.

could you guide me ?

here is my code :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setInterval(3)
                .setFastestInterval(60)
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_activity);
}

 public void circle()
 {
    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(-xxxxxx,xxxxx))
            .radius(2)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeWidth(1)
            .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
 }

public void setUpMapIfNeeded()
{
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = mapFrag.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    circle();
}

public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
{
    Log.i(TAG,"Location Services Connected.");
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(location==null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest,this);
    }
    else
    {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location)
{
    Log.d(TAG,location.toString());
    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude,currentLongitude);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here !");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,21));
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}
```

Comment: Look at either the geofencing API or the proximity alerts api

Comment: Any link or keyword ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//put this code in handler new location

```
//put this code in handler new location
if(distanceBetween(current_latlon, circle_latlon)>radius_of_circle)//radius in meters
{
    //here you can create a notification of whatever you want
}

//to calculate distance between two latlong
private float distanceBetween(LatLng latLng1, LatLng latLng2) 
{
    Location loc1 = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location loc2 = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        loc1.setLatitude(latLng1.latitude);
        loc1.setLongitude(latLng1.longitude);
        loc2.setLatitude(latLng2.latitude); 
        loc2.setLongitude(latLng2.longitude);
        return loc1.distanceTo(loc2);       //in meters
    }
```

Comment: where does it come from : current_latlon and circle_latlon and radius_of_circle ?
i'm still newbie. Tehee

Comment: 1. In your public void circle() function there is a latlon like new latlon(-xxxxx,xxxx) is your circle_latlon, 2.current_latlon is location variable in public void onLocationChanged(Location location) function,3. radius of circle is whatever you mentioned in public void circle() method.

Comment: i have create : 
Latlng latlngcircle = new LatLng(xxxxxx,xxxxx);
 and put in if statement like this :
if(distanceBetween(latLng,latlngcircle)>5
{
sendsms();
}

and when i debug in my phone it became restart the program again and again.

whats the solution ?